# Adblock plus consuming too much memory in Chrome

Tags: memory, google-chrome-extensions, adblock

I have adblock plus extension in Chrome, but it eats up too much memory causing browsing to be slow or even hanging at times. Is there a way to tackle this or any alternate ad blocking tool which is not memory intensive?

Comment: ABP (AdBlock Plus) is known to be unoptimized and a memory hog. The typical answer for a question like your's is: "Use uBlock Origin".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer is to use the regular Adblock, not Adblock Plus.

The biggest difference between them is that Adblock Plus maintains an internal database of "allowable" advertisements.  The Plus part is not for our benefit; it is theirs.  Their advertisers pay more in order to get their ads on the "allowable" list so you will see them.

Not so with regular Adblock.  It is just a blocker, no more.  It takes less memory, and it runs faster.

With the newest version, to get that last bit of performance out of it, be sure to click on the Adblock icon, go into Options and uncheck the top item labeled "Allow some non-intrusive advertising" so none can sneak through.

Comment: I didn't see much benefit when I killed Adblock Plus and left Adblock running. But maybe I need to try it under different scenarios.